# adding data after add column in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have JTable with one column as default. my program can add columns with spesific value but when i try to add data in spesific row and column, an entire row filled by data. i just want to fill data to spesific row and column. its looks like this code still read number of column as default. i dont know how to solve this. thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumn.length; i++) {
        TableColumn tbl = new TableColumn();
        tbl.setHeaderValue(i);
        table1.getColumnModel().addColumn(tbl);

    } 
table1.setValueAt(2014, 0, 14);
```

for example i want to fill data '2014' at row 0 column 14, but when i run this code, all column filled with '2014'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you manually create a `TableColumn` you need to specify which column in the `TableModel` to get the data from, otherwise they all default to column 0.

```
 TableColumn tbl = new TableColumn(i);
```

Comment: but i got an error. thanks before. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Comment: Did you actually add any rows to the TableModel? You can't just set the value of a cell unless you have added data to the model. Why are you manually adding column when you can just use the DefaultTableModel to specify the number of columns and rows. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you need more help.

Comment: i add manually column because i want to change number of column according to user's input when running time. but i'll try use DefaultTableModel and add column manually if user's input bigger than DefaultTableModel. thanks

Comment: The DefaultTableModel has an `addColumn(...)` method.